# Drupal live and staging image path

Tags: image, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

I have 2 version of my drupal site that are the live and staging. My live site is http://www.mysite.com/ and the staging is http://mystaging.com/site/www.mysite.com/.

In live site, the path of images is displaying but on my staging the images are not displaying. It’s because of the 2 subdirectory (site/www.mysite.com/) on my staging.

I would like to ask about solutions how I can display all images in my staging without editing the database or some .tpl.php file just to add “site/www.mysite.com/”. Is it possible to fix via .htaccess?

I hope someone can help me or enlighten me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `$base_url` variable in `sites/default/files/settings.php` for your local copy, that should let you set an absolute base path for your site